# jquery - turning "autocomplete" to off for all forms (even ones not loaded yet)

Tags: jquery, forms

So, I've got this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
});
```

It works great for all forms already existing. The problem is, some forms of mine are in pop ups loaded throught ajax. This won't apply to them since they're "loaded" later.

I know there's a live() function - but that's only for attaching events. What's a good way to apply this to *all* forms?

Thanks.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You could bind a live event to the focus event and then change the attribute on that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':input').live('focus',function(){
        $(this).attr('autocomplete', 'off');
    });
});
```

As of jQuery 1.7 [jQuery.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was deprecated. This code would now look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( document ).on( 'focus', ':input', function(){
        $( this ).attr( 'autocomplete', 'off' );
    });
});
```

Comment: the live() function is now deprecated http://api.jquery.com/live/ you should now use on http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @AndyBrudtkuhl no reason to down vote a 3 year old answer because its a little out of date.  I have updated the answer to be a litte more up-to-date.

Comment: I downvoted because it didnt work - that not the point of the downvote? I left a comment noting why along with an updated answer. Seems like proper Stack Etiquette to me. I removed my downvote now that it's clear that the original answer was deprecated. Thanks for updating.

Comment: @AndyBrudtkuhl I normally add comment stating that the answer need to be updated. Once you have 2000 rep points you can edit answer to update them when they go out of date.

Answer (score 5):

The live event is now deprecated, you should us the on event instead. This will attach to every input in the DOM no matter if it's created yet or not. It will then add the autocomplete="off" attribute to that input.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('focus', ':input', function() {
    $(this).attr('autocomplete', 'off');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use jquery could don't be enough, because some browsers like chrome could load the 'autocomplete' saved data before document is ready ( $(document).ready)

jquery works like this

```
$('input, :input').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```

but add manually `autocomplete='off'` to your input tags could be more efficient

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me in Chrome as well.

```
$("#autocmpldisablechk").click(function () {
    if (!$(this).is(":checked")) { 
        // enable autocomplete
        $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
            disabled: false
        });
    }
    else { 
        // disable autocomplete
        $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
            disabled: true
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I set autocomplete "off" by jQuery but not working and then change "off" to  "nope" and that worked for me:

jQuery:

```
$("form input[type=text]").attr("autocomplete", "nope");
```

HTML:

```
<input id="name" type="text" autocomplete="nope" />
```