# set autocomplete off in jquery modal dialog

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-dialog

I want to set autocomplete off each and every Jquery modal dialog. I don't want to do this by going through every single modal dialog and set the attribute to false. I'm just wondering is there a generic event we can fire after modal dialog is initialised? I turned off autocomplete in the html forms by using the following code in Document.ready function. But this doesn't work for Jquery modal. I'm looking for something similar.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {       
    $(this).find(":input[type=text]").each(function () {
        $.SetAutoCompleteOff(this);
    });
});
```

Comment: Use this:

$(this).attr('autocomplete', 'off');

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860712/jquery-turning-autocomplete-to-off-for-all-forms-even-ones-not-loaded-yet

Comment: Hi Sheetal, that's what I do inside the $.SetAutoCompleteOff(this) function :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch `dialogcreate` event:

```
$( window ).on( "dialogcreate", function(event, ui) { 
    //do what you need to do
});
```

Like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BRG9a/1/