# Turn off autocomplete in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, autocomplete

I have a site on Laravel. It has a big amount of text inputs. So, I want to disable autocomplete for all of text inputs, I know about "autocomplete=off", but it's too long to add it to all of my forms!
Is the simpler solution exists?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2860821/4402190) may help you :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('input').attr('autocomplete','off');
});
```

EDIT: only works for jquery

Comment: May want to add this solution requires jquery, since jquery shouldn't be assumed to be included in their project.

Answer (score 6):

You can append

```
autocomplete="off"
```

to your form to get this behavior.

```
<form method="POST" autocomplete="off">
// ... all inputs
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

add the attribute  `autocomplete="new-password"`
`<input type="text" autocomplete="new-password">`

Comment: your solution works but please add a brief explanation or reference

Comment: <input type="text" autocomplete="new-password">
the value new-password is telling to the browser to not fill it by value registered in cookies

Comment: edit your answer and update it with explanation and provide any reference if possible